# Get all operations from AzMan

Tags: c#, security, azman

I'm trying to fetch a list of operations related to user.

I'm using AzMan to store the application authorization rules.

How can i get list of operations per user using EntLib 4.1 SecurityApplicationBlocks or any other way?

[C#]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the AZROLESLib namespace.

Basically, Role Definitions contain operations or tasks, which contain in turn operations.

Role Assignments link Users or Groups -which contain in turn Users- with Role Definitions.

Then, to get the lists of operations assigned to a user, you need to get the roles assignments the user is in, directly or indirectly through a group, and get the operations assigned to that role assignment, either directly or indirectly through a task.

Some info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998336.aspx).